# I want when the user input is 'y' for yes, a text file will be made, and when the input is 'n', no text file to be made

Tags: python-3.x, text, input, output

Essentially, what I want is when the user answers 'y' to a question, for the script to output to a text file, and when the user answers 'n', for it no simply continue on, not making a text file.
example:

```
print('Do you like Python? (y/n)')

logask = input()

if 'logask' == 'y':
    file = open("testlog.txt", "w")
    file.write("Thanks for the feedback!")
    file.close()
else:
    print('Oh, that\'s too bad...')
```

but when i run this, it outputs the 'else' response even if I answer 'y'.

Comment: You're comparing the literal string `'y'` with the literal string `'logask'`, **not** the string object assigned to the name `logask`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Well shoot, thanks a bunch, I see what you mean now. Now how would I go about fixing that? And sorry if that's a silly question, I'm a very early beginner.

Comment: Remove the quotes: `if logask == 'y':`

Comment: Additional suggestion: while debugging the logic, substitute something like `print("Open, write, close file") for the actual operatons.

Comment: @jonrsharpe please post this as an answer. It answers the question, no need to only comment.

Comment: @greschd this is just a typo, the question should be closed

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing two strings.  What you should do is

```
print('Do you like Python? (y/n)')

logask = input()

if logask == 'y':
    file = open("testlog.txt", "w")
    file.write("Thanks for the feedback!")
    file.close()
else:
    print('Oh, that\'s too bad...')
```

Also, you may want to append to the instead of overwriting it `file = open("testlog.txt","A")` .  If you make the file ahead of time, then you'll know how many times it was answered.